# Creating Gallery with one content type

Tags: views, 7

I am able to create nested galleries with help of multiple content types and views, but is there any way that I can create nested gallery with one or two content types. I really don't want to make it messy by using multiple content types.

Comment: What does nested gallery mean? Can you explain more about your endeavor?

Comment: You can just use filters in views and restrict the content type to be the one you want